# Add column values ​considering Dates

Tags: r

I would like to create a new database from the `df` database I entered below. My idea is to create a base where only have one day per line. For example, instead of inserting 4 rows for 01/07/2021, it will only be 1, this way the values ​​of the columns of those days will be added.

```
df <- structure(
  list(Id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
     date1 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-04-02",
                 "2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03",
                 "2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-08",
                 "2021-04-07","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-04-10"),
       Week= c("Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday",
               "Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Thursday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday"),
       DTPE = c("Ho","Ho","Ho","Ho","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","Ho","Ho"),
       D1 = c(8,1,9, 3,5,4,7,6,3,8,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3), DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,7,3),
       DR02 = c(8,1,4,3,3,4,1,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3), DR03 = c(7,5,4,3,3,4,1,5,3,3,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),
       DR04= c(4,5,6,7,3,2,7,4,2,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),DR05 = c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))

> df
   Id      date1     Week DTPE D1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05
1   1 2021-07-01 Thursday   Ho  8    4    8    7    4    9
2   1 2021-07-01 Thursday   Ho  1    1    1    5    5    5
3   1 2021-07-01 Thursday   Ho  9    4    4    4    6    4
4   1 2021-07-01 Thursday   Ho  3    3    3    3    7    3
5   1 2021-04-02   Friday       5    3    3    3    3    3
6   1 2021-04-02   Friday       4    4    4    4    2    2
7   1 2021-04-02   Friday       7    3    1    1    7    1
8   1 2021-04-02   Friday       6    6    6    5    4    5
9   1 2021-04-02   Friday       3    3    3    3    2    3
10  1 2021-04-02   Friday       8    7    7    3    1    7
11  1 2021-04-03 Saturday       2    2    2    2    2    2
12  1 2021-04-03 Saturday       3    3    3    3    3    3
13  1 2021-04-03 Saturday       4    4    4    4    4    4
14  1 2021-04-03 Saturday       6    6    6    6    6    7
15  1 2021-04-03 Saturday       7    7    7    7    7    7
16  1 2021-04-08 Thursday       8    8    8    8    8    8
17  1 2021-04-08 Thursday       4    4    4    4    4    4
18  1 2021-04-07   Friday       2    2    2    2    2    2
19  1 2021-04-09   Friday       6    6    6    6    6    6
20  1 2021-04-10 Saturday   Ho  2    7    2    4    4    4
21  1 2021-04-10 Saturday   Ho  3    3    3    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may do a grouping by 'Id', along with 'date1' and 'Week', then `summarise` the `numeric` columns to get the `sum` in `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Id, date1, Week) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform this using the following code:

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>%
  group_by(Id, date1, Week) %>%
  select(D1:DR05) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)

# A tibble: 7 × 9
# Groups:   Id, date1 [7]
     Id date1      Week        D1  DR01  DR02  DR03  DR04  DR05
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2021-04-02 Friday      33    26    24    19    19    21
2     1 2021-04-03 Saturday    22    22    22    22    22    23
3     1 2021-04-07 Friday       2     2     2     2     2     2
4     1 2021-04-08 Thursday    12    12    12    12    12    12
5     1 2021-04-09 Friday       6     6     6     6     6     6
6     1 2021-04-10 Saturday     5    10     5     7     7     7
7     1 2021-07-01 Thursday    21    12    16    19    22    21
```

You might want to also convert the date1 field to a DATE object, but can do that using the lubridate verbs for e.g. `ymd()` inside a `mutate`

Comment: M Daaboul, do you know why I get errors when I try to declare a variable `df<-df %>%
  group_by(Id, date1, Week) %>%
  select(D1:DR05) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)`

Comment: Good question. I think you are referring to the line which says "Adding missing grouping variables: `Id`, `date1`, `Week`". This is a message which makes us aware that the group by variables have been added again even though the select was made on D1:DR05

Comment: Yeah isn't a problem. It is for information purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

Base `R` with `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(cbind(D1, DR01, DR02, DR03, DR04, DR05) ~ Id+date1+Week, df, sum)
```

Output:

```
 Id      date1     Week D1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05
1  1 2021-04-02   Friday 33   26   24   19   19   21
2  1 2021-04-07   Friday  2    2    2    2    2    2
3  1 2021-04-09   Friday  6    6    6    6    6    6
4  1 2021-04-03 Saturday 22   22   22   22   22   23
5  1 2021-04-10 Saturday  5   10    5    7    7    7
6  1 2021-04-08 Thursday 12   12   12   12   12   12
7  1 2021-07-01 Thursday 21   12   16   19   22   21
```